# Use Task or something else?

Tags: c#, real-time, voip, naudio

I am writing in C#.

I have a Real-Time audio player that plays incoming voice from IP Phone. I have a `byte[] Array` which gets all the voice-bytes when it comes in, and when the user presses the PLAY button, I start playing it. I also have STOP and PAUSE buttons. I am using NAudio for this, BufferedWaveProvider and Waveout Classes.

CODE IN PLAYER CLASS:

```
public void PlayCall(Call call)
{
         byte[] mixedBuffer = new byte[320];
         while (call.PlayerIndex < call.AudioArray.Length) // The AudioArray keeps getting bigger
         {
             if (_state == PlayerState.PAUSED || _state == PlayerState.STOPPED)
             // either STOP or PAUSE button is clicked
                  break;
             for (int i = 0; i < 320; i++)
             {
                  mixedBuffer[i] = (byte)(call.AudioArray[call.PlayerIndex + i];
             }
             call.PlayerIndex += 320;
             Thread.Sleep(20); // This is in order to synchronize the receiving and playing of the packets. 
             try
             {
                  AddSamples(mixedBuffer);
                  Waveout.Play();
             }
             catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
             {
                  _bufferedWaveProvider.ClearBuffer();

             }
             finally
             {
                  ClearByteArray(ref mixedBuffer);
             }
         }
}

public void StopCall(Call call)
{        
    _state = PalyerState.STOPPED;
    call.PlayerIndex=0;
    Waveout.Stop();
}

public void PauseCall(Call call)
{
    _state = PlayerState.PAUSED;
    Waveout.Pause();
}
```

the `_state` is for the State of the call (PLAYING, STOPPED, PAUSED).
As you can see, When PLAY is pressed, It keeps playing until STOP/PAUSED is pressed, then it breaks. (the WHILE Loop).

My problem is after I press the buttons a little bit, at some point The Waveout.PLAY doesn't work anymore and therefore the `BufferedWaveProvider` is getting full and crashes. (it happens sometime after two clicks, and sometimes after 10, changing).

I think it has something to do with the way I am calling the methods. Maybe some mix-up with `Threads`/`Tasks`, or not making sure one of the methods is over.. it's like this:

CODE ON THE VIEW-MODEL:

```
private void ExecutePlayCallMethod(Call call)
{
    call.Player.State = PlayerState.PLAYING;
    Task.Run(() => call.Player.PlayCall(call)); // 
}

private void ExecutePauseCallMethod(CAll call)
{
    Task.Run(() => call.Player.PauseCall(call));
    call.Player.State = PlayerState.PAUSED;
}

private void ExecuteStopCallMethod(Call call)
{
    call.Player.State = PlayerState.STOPPED;
    Task.Run(() => call.Player.StopCall(call));
}
```

Help Please? I have been struggling with this for a long time..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that calling `Waveout.Play()` multiple times is the problem.  You only need to call `Play()` once, then feed samples into the source wave provider (your `BufferedWaveProvider` instance) and the library will take care of the rest.  When the wave provider is empty the `WaveOut` object will continue to play silence until you provide more samples.

This can all be achieved in a single thread, incidentally.  Create the `WaveOut` instance, create a `BufferedWaveProvider` as a sample buffer and set it running.  Then when the audio data is available all you have to do is add the data to the `BufferedWaveProvider` and it will be played.

The `BufferedWaveProvider` uses a thread-safe internal buffer, so it's safe to add from a different thread if you feel that you really need to do so.

Comment: Thank you! its seems to be working after I changed it, I just took the Waveout.Play out of the WHILE loop. one more question - what is the difference between the Waveout.Stop and Waveout.Pause? I read somewhere that one of them clears the buffer and the other doesn't?